# Liferay 7.4 development using SDK

Tags: java, liferay, portlet, liferay-7, liferay-ide

SO I am getting back into portlet and service development using Liferay. I have Liferay Portal 7.4 up and running and the Eclipse Development Studio. Is there an SDK I need to download like older versions?
When I try to develop a portlet, it asks for the SDK. Any help appreciated.

Installed 7.4 portal on linux  - up and running.
Eclipse Liferay studio - need Liferay SDK or whatever they require for 7.4

Comment: It seems that the documentation already provides the answer. Please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

You have the option between Liferay Workspace (an opinionated gradle), pure gradle, or maven.

My recommendation is to go with Liferay Workspace. You can see a comparison of the three options in [Liferay's blade samples](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-blade-samples/). Though looking at it, the pure gradle option might be gone by now.

You mention Developer Studio: It should offer to create a Liferay Workspace. And then you'd create your modules in the workspace. You can also run your server from there.

As you're used to the older versions: If possible, go with the modularized features (e.g. OSGi based), or even better look up the new "Client Extensions", as they're a lot more lightweight and easier to maintain than server-slide plugins and the old WAR style plugins.

Comment: Thank you Olaf for your advice. I did manage to get my workspace working.